# Ansible playbook run with sudo privilege and one of the task without sudo privilege

Tags: linux, azure-devops, ansible, devops

```
---
- name: Example playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Configure Azure ADO agent
      command: "/opt/config.sh --unattended --url <url> --auth pat --token <token> --pool <pool_name> --agent Agent0 --replace"
    - name: Start Azure ADO agent service
      become: true
      systemd:
        name: azureagent.service
        state: started
        enabled: yes
```

ansible playbook should run sudo user and the Configure Azure ADO agent task should run as non sudo user

---

I tried `become: false` in the task but it is not working as expected. Any solution

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling your playbook? Take a look at [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). Variables defined on playbook invocation take precedence

Comment: Also, you're mentioning 

   > I tried become: false in the task but it is not working as expected

- What was the outcome that you got? 
- What user are you expecting to use to start the service? (note that the user will need administrative permissions to modify/start services)
- Which user do you expect to execute that action?
- Have you tried with `become_user` ?

Comment: @HiroCereal calling the playbook as a sudo user

Comment: CarlosMonroyNieblas  - tried that as well No use